# How to persist Snap SVG objects?

Tags: snap.svg

After one drawn his playground, and his visitor edited this and that (mainly by dragging), how to store the new state? Is there any proven roads to take?

Comment: Maybe dump s.outerSVG() into an xmltojson type converter, send to somewhere which retrieves and stores in a db ?

Comment: Note, this wouldn't store things like animation though (unless svg animation, not Snap animation), but it would save the svg markup.

Comment: @Ian, outerSVG() worked for me, please provide it as an answer! :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snap provides element.outerSVG() as well as element.innerSVG() which will provide the relevant markup.

This hopefully will help, you can convert to some other format and send to an sql database if needed (have done similar in the past).

What won't be stored though is Snap animations, so that would need a different workaround, but it doesn't sound like that is needed in this case.